# How to run checkbox click handler without toggling checkbox?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I've written some jQuery code like this:

```
$('#checkbox').click(function() {
    // do stuff
});

function myFunction() {
    $('#checkbox').click();
}
```

The desired behavior here is for the checkbox click handler to be invoked when myFunction executes.  However, the behavior I observe is that the click handler runs and the checkbox is toggled.  How can I run the click handler without toggling the checkbox?

Comment: Try using `.change()`.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon, there are a lot of suggested answers that are assuming different things. Perhaps you could clarify exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: I believe that the question is clear: I want to run the code in the checkbox's click handler without toggling the checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#checkbox').triggerHandler("click");
```

Or make your click handler a function that you can call directly.

Comment: It works because it does not fire an actual event, it only calls the handlers. [The doc](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) fyi

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I learnt a little bit reviewing the relevant jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$('#checkbox').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do stuff
});
```

See [**working demo**](http://tinker.io/ccb8c/1)

---

Another option to differentiate when called from myFunction() or not:

```
$('#checkbox').click(function(event, caller) {
    if (caller == 'MF') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    // do stuff
    $(this).parent().append('<span>It wasn\'t checked</span><br>');
});

function myFunction() {
    $('#checkbox').trigger('click', ['MF']);
}

$('#clk').on('click', myFunction );
```

See [**working demo**](http://tinker.io/ccb8c/2)

Comment: What happens when a user clicks the checkbox and acutally want it to toggle ?

Comment: lots of answers but this is the only one that even appears to be trying to solve the issue. @adeneo, OP specifically said he doesn't want it to toggle (for whatever reason)

Comment: @smerny - The OP specifically said he did'nt want it to toggle when the event is triggered from another function, not always ?

Comment: @adeneo Just call (or not) `.preventDefault()` conditionally then, but the OP has not specify what that condition would be..

Comment: The condition would be to not check the checkbox when the event handler is triggered from another function. How do you intend to solve that conditionally ?

Comment: I would then pass an extra param when calling from `myFunction` then, to differentiate them.

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke a method when the checkbox is changed so you can call the same method outside of the click event:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
    someMethod();
});

function myFunction(){
    someMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you do the processing in the function and have the click handler invoke the function:

```
function myFunction() {
    // do stuff
}

$('#checkbox').click(function() {
  myFunction()
});
```